# programming idiom for reading a one-record csv file into class fields

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, csv

Suppose i want to read the following file:

```
TestFile;100
```

into the fields of the class:

```
public class MyReader { 
    String field1;
    Integer field2;
}
```

There are two slightly different ways to read the content:

public class MyReader {

```
public void loadValues(File file) throws IOException {

    //a generic method that reads the content file to a string throwing an IOException
    String line = readFileToString(file);
    String[] values = line.split(";");

    field1=values[0];
    field2=Integer.parseInt(values[1]);

}

//then i'll have well known getters:

public String getField1() {
  return field1;
} 

public Integer getField2() {
  return field2;
}
```

Now the second idiom:

```
private String[] values; //made the values a class field

public void loadValues(File file) throws IOException {

    //a generic method that reads the content file to a string throwing an IOException
    String line = readFileToString(file);

    values = line.split(";");

}

public String getField1() {
  return values[0]
} 

public Integer getField2() {
  return Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
}
```

the big difference is in exception management. 
I deliberately omitted to catch two runtime exceptions that may happen in both cases:

- `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the file contains less than two fields
- `NumberFormatException` if the Integer parsing fails

**First approach**
All fields are loaded at startup. Sufficient that one of them is not parsable, i get the `NumberFormatException`. If there are less fields than the required i'll get the out of bounds exception. That sounds good, expecially if i want to ensure the correctness of all the field values behind the fact that i will use a specific one: fail fast paradigm. 
Suppose that i have one hundred fields, that the record contains an error that in turn is logged to a file for troubleshooting. As is, this code gives something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
```

that is: i get the error, the value that caused the error, the line number that gives the error, but NOT the field name. Good for the developer, not so good for the system engeneer that normally has not access to the source code.

**Second approach**
The fields are "extracted" and parsed from the data string *only when they are accessed through getters*.
Each getter may return the two errors described above, in the very same circumstances. 
There is a certain degree of "fault tolerance" as opposed to "fail fast paradigm". If the 100th field of the record contains an incorrect value, but the client of the class doesn't call for its getter, the exception will never be thrown.
On the other hand, when the getter of a incorrect value is called, the logged exception will contain the information of which field caused the problem (in the stack trace):

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)

at com.test.MyReader.getField2(MyReader.java:39)

at com.test.MyReader.test(MyReader.java:33)
at com.test.MyReader.main(MyReader.java:16)
```

**Question(s)**

Both approaches has pros and cons, and one can say that the decision on which one adopt is context-dependent. The questions are:

- getters and setters are a javabeans subject. is it "acceptable" that they return exceptions?
- the class in the two approaches may apparently have the same interface, but since they have a completely different architecutre of exception, the client is supposed to use them in a completely different way. So how to rapresent this fact to the client? Maybe the getters semantic is misleading, perhaps there is a more eloquent way?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the second approach won't work as you store the values[] array as local variable and it won't be accessible to other functions (getters in your case).

Second don't throw the exceptions in your getters as you api you expose will be misleading and won't conform to any convention.

Third, instead of parsing the string yourself, consider using a ready to use library for csv parsing and don't reinvent the wheel, eg. http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Fourth, create a simple POJO object for the csv records, you can check for erros while assigning the values to each fields and then throw the exception or not, provide default values etc.

Hope that helps

Comment: ok, the local variable should be a field, that's obviously a typo in coping and mixing my class. i've corrected that.